# function composition - $n$ times

Tags: calculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Please consider this function:
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{{\sqrt[6]{{1 + {x^6}}}}}
$$

What would be the value of the composition ($n$ times):
$$f \circ f\circ\cdots \circ f =\; ?
$$

I tried doing it manually, maybe finding a pattern. I don't see another way solving it at the moment.

Comment: What's $f \circ f$? You have the idea right, you need to find a pattern.

Comment: As @Lost said. If you tried it and didn't see a pattern, you must have made a mistake in your calculation. Slow down and be careful.

Comment: This question is asked recently

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581037/what-is-the-the-n-times-composition-of-f-fracx-sqrt1x2/581051#581051

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as it was mentioned in comments, observe what $f \circ f$ is
$$
(f \circ f )(x)= \frac {\frac x{\sqrt[6]{1+x^6}}}{\sqrt[6]{1+\frac {x^6}{1+x^6}}} = \frac x{\sqrt[6]{1+x^6} \sqrt[6]{\frac {1 + 2x^6}{1+x^6}}} = \frac x{\sqrt[6]{1+2x^6}}
$$
Now, assume that
$$
f_k(x) = \underbrace{\left ( f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f\right )}_{k\ \text{times}} (x) = \frac x{\sqrt[6]{1+k x^6}}
$$
Try to find $f_{k+1}(x)$:
$$
f_{k+1}(x) = (f \circ f_k) (x) = \frac {\frac x{\sqrt[6]{1+kx^6}}}{\sqrt[6]{1+\frac {x^6}{1+kx^6}}} = \frac x{\sqrt[6]{1+kx^6} \sqrt[6]{\frac{1+(k+1)x^6}{1+kx^6}}} = \frac x{\sqrt[6]{1+(k+1)x^6}}
$$
Therefore, according to the principle of mathematical induction
$$
f_n(x) = \underbrace{\left ( f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f\right )}_{n\ \text{times}}(x) = \frac x{\sqrt[6]{1+n x^6}},\quad n \in \mathbb N
$$

Comment: Also a very good answer. A little more laborious than what Berci's answer implies, but nonetheless, this is good.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$f(x)=\sqrt[6]{1-\frac1{1+x^6}}$$

Comment: This is a very good hint. A little thinking and the answer becomes obvious.

Comment: This is really awesome. Took me a while to get what you did here: $f(x) = \frac{x}{{\sqrt[6]{{1 + {x^6}}}}} \\ = \sqrt[6]\frac{x^6}{{{{1 + {x^6}}}}} \\ = \sqrt[6]\frac{(x^6+1)-1}{{{{1 + {x^6}}}}}$